# convert a string delimited by comma into list in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list

I have a dataframe which has two columns. Each column has comma separated string. I am trying to convert this string into list and hence I can subtract  two lists as  `a_b = list(set(a) - set(b))` for each row for the following dataset.

```
  Col1      Col2
  a,b,c,f   d,f,g
  d,g       w,a,d
  f,g,h     f,g,h
```

I tried converting items into list as below

`df1['Col1']tolist()`

But it doesn't seem to work. Thanks.

Comment: Check [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) : `df['Col1'].str.split(',')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split a comma-separated string to `list`.  You can also use `apply(set)` for your specific purposes IIUC:

```
(df['Col1'].str.split(',').apply(set) - df['Col2'].str.split(',').apply(set)).tolist()
```

[out]

```
[{'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'g'}, set()]
```